# Python sqlite can't seem to count bind parameters?

Tags: python, sqlite

I've got a little module doing some sqlite operations,
and python/sqlite can't seem to count the number of arguments
it's passing (thinks there's 7 parameters instead of 1)?

```
       sql = 'select * from tbl where stuff = ?'
       results = self.dbconn.execute(sql, things)
```

Output:

```
     File "./DeeTee.py", line 25, in stuff
       results = self.dbconn.execute(sql, things)
   ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 7 supplied.
```

Comment: what did you set `things` to?

Comment: The referenced duplicate was actually the problem - "things" needed to be "[things]"